# Share file and text

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to share file(zip) and text?

I tried but was only able to file share a zip.  I used ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE and ACTION_SEND, but still, only the same file was shared

```
  Intent share = new Intent();
        share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        share.setType("text/plain");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text ...");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "text ....");
        share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by sharing file + image with text

```
 Intent share = new Intent();
    share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    share.setType("*/*");

    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    files.add(ShareImage);
    files.add(uri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text ...");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "text ....");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share"));
```